Maxscript - Accessing the SplineShape of a node with modifiers applied to it
I have an Editable Spline node with several modifiers applied to it.
How can I access that node to have lengthInterp function working for it?
lengthInterp $MyShape_noMod 0.5
-- [4751.24,1664.78,14053.7]
lengthInterp $MyShape_extruded.baseobject 0.5
-- No ""lengthInterp"" function for Editable Spline
-- MAXScript callstack:
--  thread data: threadID:30624

--  [stack level: 0]
--  In top-level
classof $MyShape_noMod
-- SplineShape
classof $MyShape_extruded.baseobject
-- SplineShape
superclassof $MyShape_noMod
-- shape
superclassof $MyShape_extruded.baseobject
-- shape
baseobject does not work:
lengthInterp $MyShape_extruded.baseobject 0.5
-- No ""lengthInterp"" function for Editable Spline
-- MAXScript callstack:
--  thread data: threadID:30624

--  [stack level: 0]
--  In top-level
